Trying to pull a label from an array to use as a string variable
Using the TensorFlow detection model, I am trying to pull the category_name variable to use an indicator to sound an alarm when a specific category_name is found. However, I am running into an issue when pulling out the variable. Currently using a raspberry pi 4 model b (bullseye OS)
This is the Main Code I am running:
import argparse
import sys
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygame.mixer
from tflite_support.task import core
from tflite_support.task import processor
from tflite_support.task import vision
import utils

def run(model: str, camera_id: int, width: int, height: int, num_threads: int,
        enable_edgetpu: bool, alarm_label: str, cat_Name: str) -> None:

    # Variables to calculate FPS
    counter, fps = 0, 0
    start_time = time.time()

    # Start capturing video input from the camera
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

    # Visualization parameters
    row_size = 20  # pixels
    left_margin = 24  # pixels
    text_color = (225, 0, 0)  # red
    font_size = 1
    font_thickness = 1
    fps_avg_frame_count = 10

    # Initialize the object detection model
    base_options = core.BaseOptions(
        file_name=model, use_coral=enable_edgetpu, num_threads=num_threads)
    detection_options = processor.DetectionOptions(
        max_results=3, score_threshold=0.3)
    options = vision.ObjectDetectorOptions(
        base_options=base_options, detection_options=detection_options)
    detector = vision.ObjectDetector.create_from_options(options)

    # Initialize pygame mixer
    pygame.mixer.init()
    alarm_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("alarm1.wav")  # Load the alarm sound

    # Continuously capture images from the camera and run inference
    while cap.isOpened():
        success, image = cap.read()
        if not success:
            sys.exit(
                'ERROR: Unable to read from webcam. Please verify your webcam settings.'
            )

        counter += 1
        image = cv2.flip(image, 1)

        # Convert the image from BGR to RGB as required by the TFLite model.
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Create a TensorImage object from the RGB image.
        input_tensor = vision.TensorImage.create_from_array(rgb_image)

        # Run object detection estimation using the model.
        detection_result = detector.detect(input_tensor)
        #Check if the specific label is detected
        alarm_triggered = False
       
        for obj in detection_result.detections:
            print("Object 1: ", obj,"\n")
            for obj2 in obj.categories:
                print("Object 2: ", obj2, "\n")
                for obj3 in obj2.category_name:
                    print("Object 3: ", obj3)
                    if obj3 == alarm_label:
                        alarm_triggered = True
                        # Trigger the alarm sound
                        alarm_sound.play()
                        # Trigger Visual Componet
                        cv2.putText(image, "ALERT: " + alarm_label + " detected!", (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
           

        # Draw keypoints and edges on input image
        image = utils.visualize(image, detection_result)
       
     
       
        # Calculate the FPS
        if counter % fps_avg_frame_count == 0:
            end_time = time.time()
            fps = fps_avg_frame_count / (end_time - start_time)
            start_time = time.time()

        # Show the FPS
        fps_text = 'FPS = {:.1f}'.format(fps)
        text_location = (left_margin, row_size)
        cv2.putText(image, fps_text, text_location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                    font_size, text_color, font_thickness)


        # Stop the program if the ESC key is pressed.
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
        cv2.imshow('object_detector', image)

    # Release the camera and close the window
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--model',
        help='Path of the object detection model.',
        required=False,
        default='efficientdet_lite0.tflite')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--cameraId', help='Id of camera.', required=False, type=int, default=0)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--frameWidth',
        help='Width of frame to capture from camera.',
        required=False,
        type=int,
        default=800)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--frameHeight',
        help='Height of frame to capture from camera.',
        required=False,
        type=int,
        default=600)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--numThreads',
        help='Number of CPU threads to run the model.',
        required=False,
        type=int,
        default=4)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--enableEdgeTPU',
        help='Whether to run the model on EdgeTPU.',
        action='store_true',
        required=False,
        default=False)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--alarmLabel',
        help='Label to trigger alarm.',
        required=False,
        type=str,
        default='person')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--catName',
        help='Object Label Detected.',
        required=False,
        type=str,
        default='cup')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    run(args.model, args.cameraId, args.frameWidth, args.frameHeight,
        args.numThreads, args.enableEdgeTPU, args.alarmLabel, args.catName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

This is the Detection Model that categorizes and applies the bounding boxes:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tflite_support.task import processor

_MARGIN = 10  # pixels
_ROW_SIZE = 10  # pixels
_FONT_SIZE = 1
_FONT_THICKNESS = 1
_TEXT_COLOR = (0, 255, 0)  # red

def classify(
    image: np.ndarray,
    detection_result: processor.DetectionResult,
) -> np.ndarray:
 
  for detection in detection_result.detections:
    # Draw bounding_box
    bbox = detection.bounding_box
    start_point = bbox.origin_x, bbox.origin_y
    end_point = bbox.origin_x + bbox.width, bbox.origin_y + bbox.height
    cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, _TEXT_COLOR, 3)

    # Draw label and score
    category = detection.categories[0]
    category_name = category.category_name

    return category

def visualize(
    image: np.ndarray,
    detection_result: processor.DetectionResult,
) -> np.ndarray:
 
  for detection in detection_result.detections:
    # Draw bounding_box
    bbox = detection.bounding_box
    start_point = bbox.origin_x, bbox.origin_y
    end_point = bbox.origin_x + bbox.width, bbox.origin_y + bbox.height
    cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, _TEXT_COLOR, 3)

    # Draw label and score
    category = detection.categories[0]
    category_name = category.category_name
    probability = round(category.score, 2)
    result_text = category_name + ' (' + str(probability) + ')'
    text_location = (_MARGIN + bbox.origin_x,
                     _MARGIN + _ROW_SIZE + bbox.origin_y)
    cv2.putText(image, result_text, text_location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                _FONT_SIZE, _TEXT_COLOR, _FONT_THICKNESS)

  return image

This is my current output
Object 1:  Detection(bounding_box=BoundingBox(origin_x=364, origin_y=386, width=179, height=85), categories=[Category(index=14, score=0.3125, display_name='', category_name='bench')])

Object 2:  Category(index=14, score=0.3125, display_name='', category_name='bench')

Object 3:  b
Object 3:  e
Object 3:  n
Object 3:  c
Object 3:  h

My issue comes from the Object3 label. Instead of one letter per iteration I was wanting it to appear as "Object 3: bench".

maybe don't use for-loop for Object 3 and write directly print("Object 3: ", obj2.category_name), or assign directly obj3 = obj2.category_name

obj2.category_name is a string. So you're looping over the characters in the string when you do for obj3 in obj2.category_name:. What are you really intending that to do?

You probably just want if obj2.category_name == alarm_label:

As for me you don't need last for-loop and run directly
obj3 = obj2.category_name

like
obj3 = obj2.category_name

print("Object 3: ", obj2.category_name)
if obj3 == alarm_label:
    alarm_triggered = True
    # Trigger the alarm sound
    alarm_sound.play()
    # Trigger Visual Componet
    cv2.putText(image, "ALERT: " + alarm_label + " detected!", (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)


Yep, it was the for loop that was messing it up. Thank you
